# Click events not registering in starter kit

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am noticing issues with clicks not registering for Safari\Firefox when using the site starter.  I have it deployed with Firebase at https://when-ky.firebaseapp.com .

As an example, when clicking the links on the left side bar it works fine in Chrome.  In Safari\Firefox it works fine for the first click to a page.  After the first click, you often have to double click to get the pages to switch.

Thoughts?

Comment: could you share some code? It seems your span inside the anchors are creating some bubble propagation issue.

Comment: Thanks.  I set a completely fresh starter kit up at https://when-ky.firebaseapp.com/ to make sure it wasn't an error on my part.  I used "yo polymer" , "firebase init", and "firebase deploy".  The other site I have been playing with, but even on a virgin site starter kit the issue persists.  I don't see the issue when playing with the githup repo that hosts their new elements collection.  That repo does not seem to be pure 1.0 though.